# PostgreSQL char varchar datatype search speed difference

Tags: sql, postgresql

I will create index for a column in PostgreSQL.

I wonder if there is a search speed difference between **char** and **varchar** datatype?

Comment: You should not choose between `char()` and `varchar()` based on the minor speed differences in the index.  If the values are the same length, use `char()`.  If you want space-padding to a fixed length, use `char()`.  Otherwise, use `varchar()`.

Comment: Actually, you are probably best of if you completely avoid `char`. It behaves surprisingly in some cases (as decreed by the SQL standard).

Comment: The values are not same length. There will be 1M+ rows. So search speed is important for me.

Comment: I think your Quastion is perfectly answered here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-performance-impact-of-using-char-vs-varchar-on-a-fixed-size-field

Comment: @LoaStaub Thanks. But I read that post before asking this question. First my values are not fixed sized, second my db is PostgreSQL (a fork of MySQL)

Comment: If they aren't fixed size, you should use varchar or text.  Also, PostgreSQL is definitely NOT a fork of MySQL.

Comment: Could you provide some example of what are you searching? There may be best answers for data type.

Comment: @Jeremy You are right. PostgreSQL is definitely NOT a fork of MySQL. I was reading about MariaDB and I wrote a wrong comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you store a string as a `char(n)`, extra spaces are added to pad it out to length `n`.

When you perform an operation on a `char`, extra logic is required to ignore any trailing spaces.

Aside from that, `char` is identical to `varchar` in Postgres.

So, if you are dealing with variable-length strings, use `varchar`. If your values are fixed-length, then there is not much difference, though a `char` column might make your database schema slightly easier to understand.

Note that `char` cannot tell the difference between literal spaces and padding characters, which leads to some odd behaviour (as required by the SQL standard). For example, the values `''::char(1)` and `' '::char(1)` are considered equal, which is probably not what you'd expect. So if in doubt, use `varchar`.

If you have variable-length values and you don't know the maximum size, you may want `text` instead. Storage and performance of `text` is exactly the same as `varchar(n)` (all string values are handled identically by [TOAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/storage-toast.html)), but `text` has no maximum length (other than the 1GB limit which applies to all types).

Comment: At MS SQL, searching nvarchar is a bit slower than searching char because of unknown lenght of nvarchar type. If at PostgreSQL there is no difference at searching speed, I will choose varchar data type.

Comment: In Postgres, `char(n)` stores a fixed number of **characters**, not a fixed number of **bytes**. Some UTF8 characters are longer than others, which means that `char(n)` also has unknown length. So Postgres stores them in the same way as `varchar`.